# Magento 2: Recently order cannot add to cart

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I recently noticed that the sidebar of recently order items has an add to cart button.  However, when I click on this, it does do anything other than check the box. Is there a place, that can make this into a active link and have it actually add to cart?

[image]

I noticed that, this widget is created with frontend\templates\reorder\sidebar.phtml. In the code I can see this,

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="order_items[]"
                                   data-bind="attr: {id: 'reorder-item-' + id, value: id}"
                                   title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>"
                                   class="checkbox" data-validate='{"validate-one-checkbox-required-by-name": true}'/>
```

and this

```
<button type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>" class="action tocart primary">
                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                    </button>
```

Comment: It seems you are using custom theme for magento 2. So please switch your theme to magento default luma theme and then check as it works fine for luma theme.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in that box it allows you to select multiple items and then add them id suggest checking your template to see where the update has gone